# Array.filter is pulling the entire array via eventListener as opposed to the single element

Tags: javascript, filter, event-listener

I'm running into a problem where I created a `handleDelete` function that is supposed to return the array without the item selected via this function.  Instead, I'm pulling the entire array instead of the single element.

In the `createCard` function, I'm assigning the card a data-target (it's index in the array) in order to select the correct card when deleting.  I'm then adding a separate function for the button `removeBookBtn`, to create and style the button then passing that to `viewBookList` which renders the array in card format.  After that, `handleDelete` is grabbing that data-target and should return the array excluding the element selected, but again I'm getting the entire array instead of that one element.

How do I grab just that one element when `handleDelete` is called inside of `viewBookList`?

```js
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit');
const btnOpenModal = document.querySelector('.open-modal');
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector('.close-modal');
const modalElement = document.querySelector('.modal');

let myLibrary = [
  new Book('Down and Out in Paris and London', 'George Orwell', 232, true),
  new Book('Homage to Catalonia', 'George Orwell', 202, true),
  new Book('Shooting an Elephant', 'George Orwell', 368, false),
];

// let myLibrary = [];
let count = myLibrary.length - 3;

// Constructor...
function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = Number(pages);
  this.read = Boolean(read);

  // Methods
  this.bookInfo = function () {
    const wasRead = this.read === true ? 'read' : 'not read';
    console.log(
      `${this.title} written by ${this.author}, ${this.pages} pages in length was ${wasRead}.`,
    );
  };

  return this.bookInfo();
}

function createBook(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  myLibrary = [];

  let title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
  let author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
  let pages = document.querySelector('#pages').value;
  let read = document.querySelector('#read').value;

  // Instantiate new Book object
  const newBook = new Book(title, author, pages, read); // Add ID when instantiating
  addBookToLibrary(newBook);
  clearForm();
  viewBookList(myLibrary);
}

function addBookToLibrary(book) {
  modalElement.classList.remove('open');
  return myLibrary.push(book);
}

function clearForm() {
  document.querySelector('#form').reset();
}

function setCardStyle(element, details) {
  element.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; text-align: center; background-color: #fff; padding: 1em; margin: 1em 1em 1em 0; border-radius: 5px; height: 250px; width: 250px; line-height: 1.5; box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);',
  );

  element.innerHTML = `
    <h3 class="title">${details.title}</h3>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <p>${details.author}</p>
    <p>${details.pages} pages</p>
    <p>${details.read === true ? 'Read' : 'Unread'}</p>`;
}

function createCard() {
  let bookCard = document.createElement('div');
  bookCard.classList.add('card');
  bookCard.setAttribute('data-target', `${count++}`); // Set target ID

  return bookCard;
}

function removeBookBtn() {
  let btn = document.createElement('button');
  // Style button
  btn.setAttribute(
    'style',
    'color: red; height: 2.5em; width: 50%; border-radius: 5px; margin: 0 auto; font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase; cursor: pointer;',
  );
  btn.innerHTML = 'Delete';
  return btn;
}

function handleDelete(e) {
  // Get book's data-target
  let bookIndex = parseInt(e.path[1].attributes[1].value);
  let newArray = myLibrary.find((book, index) => {
    if (index === bookIndex) {
      return book;
    }
   });
  console.log(newArray);
 
 }

function viewBookList(list) {
  const bookDiv = document.querySelector('.book-list');

  for (book in list) {
    let bookDetails = list[book];
    let renderCard = createCard();
    const deleteButton = removeBookBtn();

    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', handleDelete);
    setCardStyle(renderCard, bookDetails);

    renderCard.appendChild(deleteButton);
    bookDiv.appendChild(renderCard);
  }

  return bookDiv;
}

function addClass() {
  return modalElement.classList.add('open');
}

function removeClass() {
  return modalElement.classList.remove('open');
}

viewBookList(myLibrary);

// Event listeners
btnOpenModal.addEventListener('click', addClass);
btnCloseModal.addEventListener('click', removeClass);
submitButton.addEventListener('click', createBook);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

:root {
  --roboto: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  --pt: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: var(--roboto);
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #a6c1ee 0%, #fbc2eb 100%);
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 5px #000;
}

.modal {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.label {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.btn {
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.open-modal {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.open-modal:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal.open {
  display: flex;
}

.form {
  padding: 5em;
}


.modal-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 450px;
  position: relative;
}

.modal.open .modal-container {
  animation: move 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

.close-modal {
  font-size: 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.15s linear;
}

.close-modal:hover {
  color: #f00;
}

.book-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  gap: 2em;
}

/* Created in app.js */
/* .card {
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  <script src="scripts/app.js" defer></script>
  <title>Odin Library</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">
      <h1>Library</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="modal open">
      <div class="modal-container">
        <span id="close-modal" class="close-modal">&times;</span>
        <form action="" method="POST" name="bookForm" id="form" class="form">
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="title" class="label">title: </label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Animal Farm" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="author" class="label">author: </label>
            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" placeholder="George Orwell" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="pages" class="label">pages: </label>
            <input type="number" name="pages" id="pages" placeholder="232" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="read" class="label">read: </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="read" id="read" required>
          </div>
          <div class="button-container">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" id="submit" class="submit">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section class="card-section">
    <section>
      <!-- Add plus icon -->
      <button class="btn open-modal" id="open-modal">Add Book</button> 
      <div class="book-list">
        <!-- Container for cards -->
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inside `handleDelete` you use `.filter()` to remove the clicked book from `myLibrary` but you never assign the filtered result to `myLibrary` afterwards. `.filter` returns a _new array_ , it does not alter the array it is called on.

Comment: *grab just that one element*, use `this.value`

Comment: @David I updated the handleDelete function by assigning filter to a variable, newArray, but it's still returning the entire array

Comment: @Rajesh when I assign this.value in handleDelete the return in the console is blank.  If I just return 'this', it only returns the button element.

Comment: @David is correct. But your myLibrary array contains Book objects.  Where does book.Id come from? Your condition   book !== bookId;   is always true, thus returns everything.   Maybe study up on filter() e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: @JackJack Err, maybe I havn't been clear enough. You have to _reassign_ the `myLibrary` variable after calling `.filter`, so it should be `myLibrary = myLibray.filter( ... )`. You use `myLibrary` to track the current list of available books so you need to update it :-)

Comment: Your `myLibrary` array has book *objects*. Not book IDs. `book !== bookId` is always going to be `true` because none of the objects is equal to a number. It's not really clear how you'd use a number here - the book objects do not have a numeric ID. Nor does `e.path` even work, so I'm not sure what `parseInt(e.path[1].attributes[1].value)` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the `find()` method.

```
let newArray = myLibrary.find(book => {
  Return book === bookId
});
```

Also, please do a single line return for an arrow function if the only line is the return statement.

```
let newArray = myLibrary.find(book => book === bookId);
```

Alternatively, for readability, use something like an `if` statement.

```
let newArray = myLibrary.find(book => {
  if (book === bookId) {
    return book;
  }
});
```

One last thing, whenever you run in to an issue like this, always go to MDN **first**. The following link goes to MDN's section on Array instance methods:

[MDN Array Instance Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#instance_methods)

Hope this helps.

Comment: when I try your 3rd code snippet (for readability), it always returns the first DOM element.  I changed the ```bookId``` name to ```bookIndex``` as it seems more appropriate and am only console logging the newArray to see what's returned.  However, if I add the second ```index``` parameter and in the if statement check for equality between ```index``` and ```bookIndex``` my value is found so the match is there.  I updated my code to reflect this as well.  Still not all the way there with deleting the item but I think I'm close.

Comment: If you want the specific code in my snippets to return a single value, of which should be the element specified in bookId, then it should now work. I made an error with `!===` instead of `===`